# How can I filter an redux state by sending an array of items to it using selector pattern or reselect library

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to filter the current redux state by sending an array of items either to the mapStateToProps or using a selector or `...` But I don't know how can I do this.

I can't find an appropriate example on google!

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: well redux should be used for storing data not filtering. But if you wanna filter the stored data you could do it in the component itself the receives the array data or in the mapStateToProps when passing the array. and filtering can be accomplished via `.filter` `.find` and any other JS chain function for a single line chaining depending on what kind of filtering you require.

Comment: According to my search, one of the best ways to do it is to use either a selector pattern or reselect library. But I don't know how to use these(sending array to these as a parameter)!